# Ejecutar un script desde ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

He creado un archivo llamado `catalogo.php` en el se encuentran 2 controles HTML de tipo `select`; uno que muestra la marca de los productos, y el otro que muestra los productos según la marca seleccionada.

Contenido del archivo `catalogo.php`:

```
<select id="marca">
     <option>Marca 1</option>
     <option>Marca 2</option>
     <option>...</option>
</select>
<select id="producto">
      <option>Producto 1</option>
      <option>Producto 2</option>
      <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Bueno hasta aquí todo bien, ahora cuando seleccionas un producto debería cargar en un div toda la información *(descripción, precio, etc)* dentro de el, esto lo logré usando ajax de la misma manera que hice con el control `select` de producto y funciona perfectamente.

El detalle está en que tengo un slider con las fotos del producto el cual no se muestra porque no llega a ejecutarse el script el cual esta en un archivo aparte.

Si coloco la siguiente etiqueta al final del body de `catalogo.php`:

```
<script src="slider"></script>
```

Este script se va a ejecutar y como no encuentra la información a la que debería dar funcionamiento que serían las imágenes que carga el control `select` no curre nada *aún cuando ya lo traigo con ajax*.

Por otro lado si lo coloco dentro del archivo que realiza la consulta y se trae toda la información de los productos tampoco se llegaría a ejecutar porque tengo entendido de que ajax inserta todo como un string.

Mi pregunta es: ¿existe alguna forma de ejecutar el script y desde ajax?

Comment: Hola Cutu. Tal vez te convenga mejorar tu pregunta y agregar más detalles de tu implementación para que la gente comprenda mejor tu problema. Te recomiendo que consultes las guías ["como elaborar una buena pregunta"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y ["como crear un ejemplo"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: @Cutu, He editado su pregunta, pero es necesario que edite la pregunta con el script que está usando para el slider y adicionalmente, agregar el código completo que está implementando; ya que esto facilitaría en gran medida la comprensión de la pregunta y las respuestas generadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres es carga dinámica de scripts, si no he entendido mal.

Si usas Jquery puedes hacerlo con [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Si lo quieres sin dependencias prueba con:

```
/**
 * Carga scripts javascript que no se hayan cargado durante la carga de la pagina
 *
 * @param {string} sRuta Ruta donde se encuentre el script a cargar
 * @param {function} oCallback Callback a ejecutar despues de la carga
 * @param {string} sType Tipo que se asignara al elemento cargado, por omision "text/javascript" (hara que se interprete como tal), poner otro tipo para evitar el interprete js, ej.: text/jshtml
 * @return {boolean}
 */
JaSper_loadScript = function (sRuta, oCallback, sType){
    sType = sType || 'text/javascript';

    var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;
    var sScriptId = 'JaSper_script_' + sRuta.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d_]+/, '');

    if(!document.getElementById(sScriptId)){
        var oScript = document.createElement('script');
        oScript.setAttribute('id', sScriptId);
        oScript.setAttribute('type', sType);
        oScript.setAttribute('src', sRuta);

        oScript.onload = oScript.onreadystatechange = function (){
            if(!this.readyState || this.readyState === 'loaded' || this.readyState === 'complete'){
                oScript.onload = oScript.onreadystatechange = null;
                oCallback.call(oScript);

                if(oHead && oScript.parentNode){
                    oHead.removeChild(oScript);
                }
            }
        };

        oHead.insertBefore(oScript, oHead.firstChild);
    }
    else{
        oCallback.call(document.getElementById(sScriptId));
    }

    return true;
};
```